# Django view retrieve model id of instance just created

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a simple scenario trying to retrieve the id/pk of a model instance created in a view. The model instance is creating fine however the id/pk is returning "None". I thought I was following the code as laid out in the latest [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/) but I must be doing something wrong.

Models.py

```
class Userdownloads(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='Download_created_by',null=True,blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Views.py

```
d = Userdownloads(created_by=request.user)
d.save()
print(d.id)
```

Ive tried both `d.id` and `d.pk`

Can anybody help my see where I am going wrong? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On save call of the given example should throw an error like this:

> null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

So, here the `id` field should be [AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#autofield). For example:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

From the documentation,

> AutoField
>
> An IntegerField that automatically increments according to available IDs. You usually won’t need to use this directly; a primary
>   key field will automatically be added to your model if you don’t
>   specify otherwise

Comment: This was exactly my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify id on django models because it will automatically create for you.

```
class Userdownloads(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='Download_created_by',null=True,blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

[Here is the link to the models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/)

If it give you None then it has not been saved to the database yet.